# How to disable access to category pages

Tags: categories

I want my categories to be active and at the same time I want to make the category pages inaccessible. Is it possible? If yes, How?

**Why I want to do this? (Possibly this may help)**

I am working on a ugc website. I am asked to bring `/category/cat-name` to `/cat-name`. I am also asked to add another page `/cat-name/add` where users are allowed to post only to a specific category. It is not possible to add page `/cat-name/add` until I create a page (not category page) `/cat-name`. If I create a page `/cat-name`, it'll conflict with the category page `/cat-name`. This is why I thought I'd disable category page `/cat-name` and use a normal page at `/cat-name` to list category posts.

Comment: Do you want the categories active for organisation on the back end of the website, but not active on the front end? Might help to add a little more detail to your problem.

Comment: @ChrisMorris, did the update help? And... It is ok if the category pages are not accessible at the backend ....

Comment: Reading your other posts gave a bit of clarification. Though I'm unsure as to the end goal you're after. What is it that you're trying to build?

Comment: @ChrisMorris, Hope the update to the question answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can add something like this in your category.php.

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit;
}
```

This will redirect viewers to website homepage but category pages will be active and accessable to admins only.

Comment: editing wp files is not what I am allowed to . . . .

Comment: Hope the update to question helps . . .

Comment: category.php is a theme file, not a core file. (assuming that's what you mean by "wp files")

Comment: Oops, sorry. But I thought I'd implement a cross-theme solution.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do at least two things (possibly more, I haven't thought it all the way through), in it's simplest form:

1. Prevent category output lists from creating links:

   You'd need to emulate [`get_the_category_list()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L162) and build your own category list without anchors, or you could probably just filter out the `<a>` tags:

   ```
   add_filter( 'the_category', function ( $thelist, $sep, $parents ) {
     return strip_tags( $thelist, '<ul><li>' );
   } );
   ```
2. redirect category URLs somewhere.

   category.php

   ```
   <?php wp_redirect( home_url() );
   ```